# ECMAScript 2015/TypeScript 2 setter with objects

Tags: ecmascript-6, getter-setter, typescript2.0

How can I `set` objects in a class?

```
interface IAddress {
    streetAddress: string;
    postCode: string;
    city: string;
}

class C {
    private _data = <any> {};

    public get postAddress(): IAddress {
        return this._data.postAddress;
    }

    /*
    public set postAddress() {

    }
    */
}

let a = new C();
```

Now, when I `get` that address I have:

```
let address = a.postAddress;

/*
{
    streetAddress: "";
    postCode: "";
    city: "";
}
*/
```

Then I want to set some properties via setter (which I can't; don't know how to):

```
a.postAddress.city = 'NEW YORK';
```

But nothing happens as `a.postAddress` first gets the object and `C` class' setter will never be called. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `postAddress` getter return an object that implements the `IAddress` interface and has setters for `streetAddress`, `postCode` and `city`.